# Behaviour of sortedArrayUsingComparator

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, sorting

I'm in the process of understanding objective C blocks. Most of the time I have been dealing with async blocks for web calls. But Here I have a method for returning sorted array of custom objects (in the alphabetical order of a property).

Here Im bit confused how this block works? Is it an async call (in which case it should  yield the input array itself). Can someone explain?

```
+(NSArray*)sortedListAlphabetically:(NSArray*)_unsortedList{
    NSArray *sortedArray;
    sortedArray = [_unsortedList sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
        NSString *first = [(customObject*)a userName];
        NSString *second = [(customObject*)b userName];
        return [first compare:second];
    }];
    return  sortedArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a synchronize call during the block, you can treat the block as a function that compares two objects. With this compare function, system can sort the array. Explain by code:

`function : ^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b)` - provided by you in the block code.

NSArray sortedArrayUsingComparator do:

1. Get two objects from the array.
2. Compare this two objects by the compare function in the block. (get result of NSOrderedAscending, NSOrderedSame,NSOrderedDescending )
3. Put the object to new array according the the compare result.
4. Continue one if there are still object left in origin array.
5. return the new array after all objects sorted.

(The operation for 1,4 may be different based on the sort algorithm but the basic ideas is the same.)

Answer (score 0):

It is worth mentioning that this method doesn't provide itself a recursive looping in multiple sort criteria operations. Let's say you want sort an array like this `unsortedList = @[@{@"name":"...", @"isFavourite":"..."},...]` placing the favourite before not favourite elements and sorting each subgroup alphabetically by name, the following code will not work:

```
sortedArray = [unsortedList sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id  _Nonnull obj1, id  _Nonnull obj2) {
        NSDictionary *one = (NSDictionary*)obj1;
        NSDictionary *two = (NSDictionary*)obj2;
        NSString *name1 = [one objectForKey:@"name"];
        NSString *name2 = [two objectForKey:@"name"];
        NSInteger isFav1 = [[one objectForKey:@"isFavourite"] integerValue];
        NSInteger isFav2 = [[two objectForKey:@"isFavourite"] integerValue];
        if (isFav1 > isFav2)
            return NSOrderedAscending;
        else if (isFav1 < isFav2)
            return NSOrderedDescending;
        else
            return [name1 compare:name2];
    }];
```

You have to introduce one or more `for` loops inside the block, so I find more efficient for complex sorting operations to use `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:` like this:

```
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor1 = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"isFavourite" ascending:NO];
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor2 = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
sortedArray = [unsortedList sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[descriptor1, descriptor2]];
```